# What is the best way to count collection of dates by quarter?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a collection of dates:

```
 IEnumerable<DateTime> Events;
```

And I want to count and bucket then into quarters (Q1 2011, Q2 2011, etc.) where each quarter represents three-month buckets.

I started doing this "manually" with a loop and a separate dictionary, but I thought there might be a more elegant way using LINQ, etc. to do this conversion.

I want to end up with a data structure that looks like this:

```
 public List<QuarterInfo> QuarterBreakdown
```

where QuarterInfo is simply:

```
 public class QuarterInfo
 {
     public int QuarterOfYear; //1, 2, 3 or 4
     public int Year;
     public IEnumerable<DateTime> Events;
 }
```

NOTE that the above was my thinking, but I am more than open to suggestions on other ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure LINQ, using `GroupBy`:

```
var result = Events
    .Select(d => new { DateTime = d, Q = (d.Month - 1) / 3 })
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Q, a.DateTime.Year })
    .Select(a => new QuarterInfo
        {
            Events = a.Select(s => s.DateTime),
            QuarterOfYear = a.Key.Q + 1
        });
```

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to factor in events in multiple years. they should go into seperate buckets.  An event in Jan 2010 should not go in the same bucket as Jan 2011

Comment: i think d.Month / 3 is incorrect as i am seeing Sept dates go into Q = 4 and December dates go into Q = 5. i think it might be a division issue

Answer (score 1):

```
var QuarterBreakdown =
    from date in Events
    group date by date.Year * 4 + (date.Month - 1) / 3 into quarters
    select new QuarterInfo
    {
        Events = quarters,
        Year = quarters.Key / 4,
        QuarterOfYear = quarters.Key % 4 + 1
    };
```